# How did consumer handle the messages without start a new Thread in NATS-JetStream?

Tags: java, nats.io, countdownlatch, nats-jetstream

Recently I've been learning NATS-JetStream, and I came across some sample code on GitHub.  Here is the [simple java code of the NATS client](https://github.com/nats-io/nats.java/blob/main/src/examples/java/io/nats/examples/jetstream/simple/MessageConsumerExample.java):

This code primarily accomplishes the following task:

1. declare a MessageHandler and a CountDownLatch.
2. create a consumer (MessageConsumer) before calling the latch.await() method.

As far as I know, the latch.await() method will block the current Main Thread and put it into a block state.

**My first question**

Given that the await() method of CountDownLatch blocks the current thread,

How can the handler process message when new messages arrive in the already blocked current thread?

**My second question**

If I want to run a program that never stops,
is it a good idea to use CountDownLatch and not invoke CountDownLatch.countDown(), allowing the consumer to continuously listen to the NATS subject/stream?

I tried running the sample code and wrote my own program to publish some messages to JetStream.

After publishing the first message, the consumer program successfully received the message.

However, when I published the second message, the consumer displayed a "severe: heartbeatAlarm warning" message.